# Configure Apache2 to only respond to virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, security, hacking, http-status-code-404

Have a server that, while reviewing the logs, appears to get hit many many many times a day via the direct ip address by automated scripts looking for vulnerabilities.  Entries like:

```
[Sat Jul 31 17:45:01 2010] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] script '/var/www/phpMyAdmin' not found or unable to stat
```

I run a number of virtual servers on this system, but nothing at the direct IP.  All of these attempts are resulting in a 404, which is fine, but I'd rather not even have the server respond.  Any way to configure, say /sites-available/default to simply drop every request it receives?

Thanks

Comment: Identical to this, answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/175679/how-can-i-get-apache-to-not-respond-to-an-ip-only-request/175685#175685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a default site, it will use the first vhost applicable for site unless I'm wrong. Just use a default vhost that doesn't do anything and returns 404 or 403 for everything.