# Name-based apache setup

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting

What I'm trying to do is to show a page when a domain is visited but if someone tries to visit directly by ip (and not using the domain) i want to show him another page.

Classic name based apache hosting right?

Well my only question is what should i put in ServerName and/or ServerAlias?

What i've done till now is to uncomment this line:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

and i've setup 2 virtual hosts like this (specific info hidden):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin someone@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/default/
        ServerName {my-dedicated-ip}
        ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/default/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/default/custom.log gk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin some-email@valid-domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/something/httpdocs/
    ServerName valid-domain.com
    ServerAlias *.valid-domain.com
    ErrorLog "| /usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l /var/www/vhosts/something/logs/error.log.%Y.%m.%d 86400"
    CustomLog "| /usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l /var/www/vhosts/somthing/logs/custom.log.%Y.%m.%d 86400" gk
</VirtualHost>
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Oh, and i have a single dedicated ip.

I also just found this: [How can I get Apache to not respond to an IP-only request?](https://serverfault.com/questions/175679/how-can-i-get-apache-to-not-respond-to-an-ip-only-request) according to which, my setup should work. It should visit the first vhost it finds. But it doesn't. It goes to the second.

EDIT:
apachectl -S output:

```
[root@me conf.d]# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1015)
         port 80 namevhost {my-dedicated-ip} (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1015)
         port 80 namevhost valid-domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1023)
                 wild alias *.vaild-domain.com
Syntax OK
```

and yes the 2 vhosts are in the same file.

Comment: Are both vhosts defined in the same config file? What's the output of `apachectl -S`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apache 2.2 you designate a default [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost) with the `_default_` directive which should match for both the ip-address as well as all domain names that are not explicitly defined as ServerName or ServerAlias in the subsequent VirtualHost entries.

For instance:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/default/
        ServerName default
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/something/httpdocs/
    ServerName valid-domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Finally! It's working. At first it didn't but i remember to hit a Ctrl+F5 and the other page came up. Thank you very much. I have tried that with the _default_ but not with ServerName default..
So that was it!

Another question. You say specifically for Apache 2.2.
If i update to 2.4 will i need to change something?

Comment: In apache 2.4 the first VirtualHost entry is the default and IIRC the `_default_` isn't a valid directive anymore, in apache 2.2 the `_default_` need not be the first virtual host entry.